# Ionic 2/3 filetransfer upload error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am always getting one of these errors even if the image is uploaded.

Note :
 the code works sometimes when I leave the app running without any requests for a while otherwise I get the errors below .

```
// Destination URL
let url = "https://***s.me/petupload.php";

// File for Upload
let targetPath = imgpath;
// File name only
let filename = imgname;

let options: FileUploadOptions = {
fileKey: "file",
fileName: filename,
chunkedMode: false,
mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
headers:{ Connection: "close"},
params : {'fileName': filename,func: "upload"}};


let  fileTransfer: FileTransferObject =
this.filetransfer.create();



// Use the FileTransfer to upload the image
fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options,true).then(data => {
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.response));
console.log("image sent");}, err => {
console.log(JSON.stringify(err));});
```

Errors:

> {“code”:3,“source”:“file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files       /amarimg.jpg”,“target”:“https://***s.me/petupload.php",“http_status”:null,“body”:null,“exception”:"state:
>   2”}
>
> {“code”:3,“source”:“file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/amarimg.jpg”,“target”:“https://***s.me/petupload.php",“http_status”:null,“body”:null,“exception”:"expected
>   1596 bytes but received 16384”}

In my php i have the following headers

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-type:multipart/form-data");

header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-  Disposition, Content-Description');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");



$target_path = "/var/www/html/";//"uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);


if(isset($_POST['func'])){ 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "Upload and move success";
} else {
echo $target_path;
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";}
;}else{echo"no func";}
```

any thoughts ??

this issue has been solved by ewizard

should this mimeType: "multipart/form-data" be this mimeType: "image/jpeg"? you can actually remove the mimeType...it defaults to image/jpeg also maybe remove chunkedMode

however i still need to use multipart/form-data if possible thats why im leaving this issue open.

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. please follow the guidelines of asking good questions to get good answers :)

Comment: just added the code and edited the question

Comment: what about your php code? judging from what the errors look like...it might be coming from there....do you have any stray `echo` statements? and have u looked at the `php` log?

Comment: should this `mimeType: "multipart/form-data"` be this `mimeType: "image/jpeg"`? you can actually remove the `mimeType`...it defaults to `image/jpeg` also maybe remove `chunkedMode`

Comment: i think ewizard answer works , i still have to do more tests but it seems that its working, however this raises the question on how to use multipart/form-data ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved by ewizard last comment however the use of multipart is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was because I did not return a JSON back, so the parsing would go wrong:)